# Accept Rate and accepting your own answers

Tags: support, accept-rate, self-answer

Do answers to your own question not contribute towards your accept rate? My accept rate is lower than I'd expect it to be for my 'accepted answers:total questions' ratio.

Comment: It's probably about right now, actually. Yesterday though I'd accepted 9 from 11 and it was showing 80%I know it would only be about 82% but someone picked up on me not accepting enough answers so I was just wondering if your own answers contributed or not. It looks like they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your accept rate recalculation takes time to reflect on your profile. Just give it around a day's time and your accept rate will be recalculated and updated.

Your own answers to your own questions also are considered in accept rate calculations.

Comment: I knew about the catch-up time but thanks for the clarification and the answer to my question.